# Windows Registry Query (Server 2008) Powershell or Batch Scripting

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, registry

I am attempting to retrieve all the values\data from the subkeys of a registry where another value's data = X.

Example key:
    `$key = HKLM:\Software\Testbuild\Configurations\<subkeys>`

Within each subkey are the following Value/Data pairs:

```
Value   Value_Type      Data
Active  Reg_Multi_SZ    Yes
Name    Reg_Multi_SZ    LowerConfig
CString Reg_Multi_SZ    111, 222, 333
```

I would like to retrieve all the Names where the Cstring = 111 and Active = Yes.

I have a basic understanding of powershell and batch scripting but spinning my wheels on this one.  I'm not dedicated to powershell as a solution either but just to show where my thought process has been:

```
$key = HKLM:\Software\TestBuild\Configurations\test1
$regprop = (Get-ItemProperty -path $key)
$regprop.PSObject.Properties{If($_.Name -like 'Cstring' -and $_.Value -like '*111*'){Write-Host $_.Name ' = ' $_.Value}}
```

Unfortunately the best this will come up with is the actual name and value where the conditions are met, not the other value name or its data, respectively.

Any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but as this is a programmer's Q&A site, I'm afraid you're going to have to produce some code that demonstrates you made an effort at doing this on your own, rather than asking others to do the work for you.

Comment: Get all of the Keys with `Get-ChildItem -recurse`, loop over them with a `Get-ItemProperty -Name Cstring` and filter for the value you are looking for with `Where-Object`. Then on each success lookup the value you want with `Get-ItemProperty -Name Name`

Comment: Bill and Ben thank you for the prompt replies! I've added the script I have so far .. I didn't think of the -recurse switch.  Let me take another stab at it with that method.